# Custom JSON data to be parse into objects

Tags: json

i have this task to parse json data to object, as in

```
    {
"AAA" : {
       "A1" : "a1 comment",
       "A2" : "a2 comment"   
    },
"BBB" : {
      "B1" : "b1 comment"
    },
"CCC" : {
      "C1" : "c1 comment",
       "C2" : "c2 comment",
       "C3" : "c3 comment"
       "C4" : "c4 cooment"
    },
"DDD" : {
      "D1" : "d1 comment"
    }
}
```

need to be converted to objects like ,

```
class Schema {
    String tableName;
    List<Column> colData;
```

And

```
class Column {

    String columnName;
    String columnComments;
```

Since i am a beginner to json, i took to the approach of first parsing things to xml and if it works proceed to parsing xml to object.

but i am having trouble parsing the json data.

however if i replace all the single quotes with double quotes and and '=>' with ':'  and only consider AAA, i am able to parse with below code, but if i use the whole json data it throws error.

any help is deeply appreciated.

the code that i have so far is :

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("schema.sql"));
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(IOUtils.toString(fis, "UTF-8")));
            DOMResult result = new DOMResult();
            transformer.transform(new SAXSource(new JsonXmlReader("Table"), source), result);
            Node n=result.getNode();
            System.out.println(result.toString());

            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
//          Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            transformer.transform(new DOMSource(n), new StreamResult(writer));
            String xml = writer.toString();
            System.out.println(xml);
```

which works for below data:

```
{
"AAA" : {
       "A1" : "a1 comment",
       "A2" : "a2 comment"   
    }
}
```

ofcourse i had to replace all ' with " and => with :

for the json data

```
{
"AAA" : {
       "A1" : "a1 comment",
       "A2" : "a2 comment"   
    },
"BBB" : {
      "B1" : "b1 comment"
    }
}
```

the error that i see is :

```
ERROR:  'Parsing error: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: An attempt was made to insert a node where it is not permitted. '
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: net.javacrumbs.json2xml.JsonSaxAdapter$ParserException: Parsing error: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: An attempt was made to insert a node where it is not permitted. 
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(Unknown Source)


net.javacrumbs.json2xml.JsonSaxAdapter$ParserException: Parsing error: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: An attempt was made to insert a node where it is not permitted. 
    at net.javacrumbs.json2xml.JsonSaxAdapter.parse(JsonSaxAdapter.java:177)
    at net.javacrumbs.json2xml.JsonXmlReader.parse(JsonXmlReader.java:152)
```